# ASP.NET and the classic HTML form

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, forms, hidden-field

I am implementing a standard payment system, which sends some information to 3rd part form. I've a checkout object which stores all my shopping information: ID, products bought, price - you name it.

People are transfered to an ASPX page which has an implementation as seen below.

**Currently I have the following problem**:

The values send on the inputs which has the runat="server" is 0. Therefore I get an error. However, in the OnPreInit event in the code behind, i set the values of amount, accepturl and orderid. I can see the hidden fields get the correct information when the page is loaded - but when the form is fired (which apparently happens before the OnPreInit event), it is still 0.

How do I solve this problem? Basically I need to use an HTML form which opens a popup window (which HAS to show on page load), where I have to set the hidden fields. Should be quite simple, but after I've used hours on this I would really appreciate some help.

Currently my implementation is like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="BetalingMedKort.aspx.cs" Inherits="BetalingMedKort" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.epay.dk/js/standardwindow.js"></script> 
    <title></title>
</head>


<body onload="open_ePay_window()">

    <form action="SomeUrl" runat="server" method="post" name="ePay" target="ePay_window" id="ePay">
<input type="hidden" name="merchantnumber" value="MyStaticMerchantNumber" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="language" value="1" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="208" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amountField" runat="server" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="accepturl" id="acceptUrlField" runat="server" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="orderid" id="orderIdField" runat="server"  />
<input type="hidden" name="declineurl" value="SomeUrl" />

</form> 


    <div>
        If the ePay Payment Window does not open automatically please click on the button below to open it.
    <br /><br />
Notice! If you are using a pop-up blocker, you must hold down the CTRL key as you click the button.
<br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Open the ePay Payment Window" onClick="open_ePay_window()"> 
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much...

Comment: You could use an <asp:Literal> and set its .Text to be `<input type="hidden" value=`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the input values in the page's Init or Load events. ViewState isn't available during PreInit (though there may be some exceptions).

If you absolutely have to perform your logic during PreInit then this [page](http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2008/12/20/accessing-aspnet-page-controls-during-preinit/) may have a workaround for you.

Comment: I've tried setting the values in both the OnLoad, OnInit, Page_Load and the PreInit. Still no luck.

Any ideas? :-/

Comment: When are you getting the values (when they are 0)? Can you post that code? Make sure you get the values during Init, Load, or a later event (not PreInit).

Comment: My problem was I referenced wrong input fields, as I gave them an ID and runat="server", with a different ID than the name. The name then changed to my ID. Your post helped though - that was *also* a problem :-)